# ui grid custom filter generalisation

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

We have implementation of ui grid custom filter as per in the lonk below: However we want to generalize the implementation so that it can be used it with multiple columns.

However we still couldnt figure it out how directive can come to know from which column filter is getting applied. Even after trying multiple options still no succes. Any pointers will be really helpful

We tried to pass attribute for directive but this is also not working

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/tutorial/Tutorial:%20306%20Custom%20Filters

Comment: i could generalise the custom filter by knowing the column using code as below :


`code`

    angular.forEach($scope.$parent.grid.columns, function (value, key) {
            if($scope.$parent.col.colDef.field == value.field)            {
                currentColumn = value.field;
                $scope.customFilterColumnDisplayName = $scope.$parent.col.colDef.displayName;
            }
        });
`code`

Answer (score 0):

I could generalize it simply by using same tag in other files

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).